# How to trigger a seque programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a TableViewController which presents (push) a ViewController (ScannerViewController) with this code: [Bar Code Scanner](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-barcode)

There is the following method:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        found(code: readableObject.stringValue);
    }

    dismiss(animated: true)   
}
```

Instead of dismiss(animated: true) I'd like to trigger a seque. The method in the TableViewController is:

```
@IBAction func unwindWithSelectedCode(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let scannerViewController = segue.source as? ScannerViewController,
        let selectedCode = scannerViewController.code {
        myCode = selectedCode
    }
}
```

Normally I have a button which I connect to ViewControllers Exit sign on the top of the VC in the storyboard and call the method above. But I have no button. So how can I call the seque method programmatically without a button?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

replace `unwindSegueIdentifier` with your identifier

Comment: Thank's. If I put this code instead of the dismiss() method - it performs the seque but the code does not show up in the TableViewController. Any idea how to solve this?